# How to update date into a table inside a Redshift PL/SQL Stored procedure? Please share Update statement syntax inside a Redshift Stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, amazon-redshift

```
---stored procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cdw.redshift_sample_sp() AS
    $$ declare     ROWCOUNT INT ;
    rwnm           INT;
    printval       INT ;
    rec            RECORD;
    days_supplied  INT;
    sp_id          INT;
    lh_patient_id1 INT;
    ship_dt        DATE;
    next_ship_dt1  DATE;
    anticipated_dt DATE;
    days_balance   INT;
    days_diff      INT;
    counter        BIGINT;

BEGIN
    -----------------Insert Into begins---------------------
    BEGIN
        execute ' CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_variables AS (SELECT * FROM tmp_variables_new);';
        RAISE info 'CREATED TEMP TABLE';
        rwnm = (SELECT MAX(rownum) FROM tmp_variables);
        days_balance = 0;
        counter = 1;
        RAISE info 'UPDATED COUNTER';
        FOR rec IN select * FROM tmp_variables WHERE ROWNUM<=RWNM
            LOOP
                RAISE info 'INSIDE FOR LOOP';
                    days_supplied = (SELECT days_supplied1 FROM tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
                RAISE info 'days_supplied = %', days_supplied;
                sp_id = (SELECT sp_id1 FROM tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
                RAISE info 'sp_id = %', sp_id;
                    lh_patient_id1 = (SELECT lh_patient_id FROM tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
                RAISE info 'lh_patient_id1 = %', lh_patient_id1;
                ship_dt = (SELECT ship_date FROM tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
                RAISE info 'ship_dt = %', ship_dt;
                    next_ship_dt1 = (SELECT next_ship_dt FROM tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
                RAISE info 'next_ship_dt1 = %', next_ship_dt1;
                anticipated_dt = dateadd(d, days_supplied + days_balance, ship_dt)::DATE;
                RAISE info 'days_balance = %', days_balance;
                RAISE info 'Anticipated_dt = %', Anticipated_dt;
                IF (anticipated_dt > next_ship_dt1)
                THEN
                    days_balance = abs(datediff(d, anticipated_dt, next_ship_dt1));
                    RAISE info 'days_balance NOW = %', days_balance;
                ELSE
                    days_balance = 0;
                    RAISE info 'IF LOOP ENDS';
                END IF;
                execute 'UPDATE  tmp_variables  SET  next_anticipated_ship_dt = '|| Anticipated_dt::DATE || ' WHERE ROWNUM=' || COUNTER;
                RAISE info 'UPDATE STATEMENT ENDS';
                counter = counter + 1;
                RAISE info 'UPDATED COUNTER = %', COUNTER;

            END LOOP;
    END;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

COMMIT;

CALL cdw.redshift_sample_sp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a closing semicolon inside the `UPDATE` statement. The change is at `COUNTER ||';';` .

```
---stored procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CDW.redshift_sample_sp () 
AS $$
DECLARE 
    rowcount       INT ; 
    rwnm           INT; 
    printval       INT ; 
    rec            RECORD; 
    days_supplied  INT; 
    sp_id          INT; 
    lh_patient_id1 INT; 
    ship_dt        DATE; 
    next_ship_dt1  DATE; 
    anticipated_dt DATE; 
    days_balance   INT; 
    days_diff      INT; 
    counter        BIGINT;
BEGIN
-----------------Insert Into begins---------------------
    EXECUTE ' CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_variables AS (select * from tmp_variables_new);';
        RAISE INFO 'CREATED TEMP TABLE';
    rwnm = (SELECT MAX(rownum) FROM tmp_variables);
    days_balance = 0;
    counter = 1;
        RAISE INFO 'UPDATED COUNTER';
    FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM tmp_variables WHERE ROWNUM<=RWNM
    LOOP
            RAISE INFO 'INSIDE FOR LOOP';
        days_supplied=(SELECT days_supplied1 FROM tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
            RAISE INFO 'days_supplied = %', days_supplied;
        sp_id=(SELECT sp_id1 FROM tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
            RAISE INFO 'sp_id = %', sp_id;
        lh_patient_id1=(SELECT lh_patient_id from tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
            RAISE INFO 'lh_patient_id1 = %', lh_patient_id1;
        ship_dt=(SELECT ship_date FROM tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
            RAISE INFO 'ship_dt = %', ship_dt;
        next_ship_dt1= (SELECT next_ship_dt FROM tmp_variables WHERE rownum = counter);
            RAISE INFO 'next_ship_dt1 = %', next_ship_dt1;
        anticipated_dt = DATEADD(d, days_supplied + days_balance, ship_dt)::DATE;
            RAISE INFO 'days_balance = %', days_balance;
            RAISE INFO 'Anticipated_dt = %', anticipated_dt;
        IF (anticipated_dt > next_ship_dt1) THEN
            days_balance = ABS(DATEDIFF(d, anticipated_dt, next_ship_dt1));
                RAISE INFO 'days_balance NOW = %', days_balance;
        ELSE
            days_balance = 0;
                RAISE INFO 'IF LOOP ENDS';
        END IF;
        EXECUTE 'UPDATE tmp_variables '
              ||' SET next_anticipated_ship_dt = '''||anticipated_dt::DATE
              ||''' WHERE rownum = ' || COUNTER ||';';
            RAISE INFO 'UPDATE STATEMENT ENDS';
        COUNTER=COUNTER+1;
        RAISE INFO 'UPDATED COUNTER = %', COUNTER;
    END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL CDW.redshift_sample_sp ();
```

Comment: This will never run in any plsql envirolment.  PLSQL is Oracle's propitiatory extension language for sql. However, this is a PLPGSQL function, i.e. Postgres extension language for sql. So did select the wrong tag (and title) or did you post the wrong code?

Comment: Can you help me updating a date into a date field in this procedure? I was able to update sysdate in a date field, but the moment I write - EXECUTE ''update  tmp_variables  set  next_anticipated_ship_dt = anticipated_dt WHERE ROWNUM='' || COUNTER ;  Here the anticipated_dt is DATE type. Even if I do to_date(anticipated_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD') or I do cast(anticipated_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD'), I am getting error - [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "next_anticipated_ship_dt" is of type date but expression is of type integer. Any suggestions on this error ?

Comment: You need to embed single quotes in the dynamic SQL so that Redshift will interpret the value as a date. I updated the example with `'''||anticipated_dt::DATE`

Comment: Even this is not working in redshift - anticipated_dt::DATE . I got the same error - [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "next_anticipated_ship_dt" is of type date but expression is of type integer; [SQL State=42804, DB Errorcode=500310]. Any other option to convert into date. anticipated_dt is already a date.